# Gradle 'XXX' project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a problem in android studio. when I build one of the projects, but other is right.

Is there someone met it and what can i do for this?

The log of the error is:

> Gradle 'XXX' project refresh failed    Error:Unable to calculate
>   percentage: 14818 of -641575. All inputs must be >= 0

Comment: @Abhinav if you edit please edit everything at once, there are some typos and the unnecessary greeting you could have removed as well

Comment: @avalancha Thanks for your suggestion. We should concentrate on resolving the problem of user.

Comment: I'm so sorry,but there is no more details in android studio.

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem an hour ago. I did everything I could. I thought that my recent changes have broken it. Then I created a sample project that breaks too.

Then of course I decided to clean everything in project and restart my Android Studio - still it has same problem.

The only solution that could work for me is - restart machine.

And it has worked.

Reason: I don't know. However, I am happy that I don't have to worry about detailing gradle ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it by restarting Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a few minutes ago and I tried with Invalidate Caches/Restart... Try with that option! Vibes